# Change desktop app icons on mac, programatically. 2019

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, electron, desktop-application

Is there a way to change icons on desktop apps for macbooks, that replicates the same action that happens when you copy / paste icons in the finder window? Either through the terminal, node.js or anything ? I have so far tried:

1) Through the terminal, deleting and replacing the icons themselves, I don't like this because it removes the original icon completely and does not work on every app.

2) Through node.js and terminal, creating an icon? file, however this did not work on every program either, and I had trouble with permission access. If anyone have a solution for this I'd like to hear it.

3) With applescript, this worked but looping through multiple icons at once was too much for it.

I've been searching about this for days, but the information is either very limited or outdated. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

To change the icon of an application, I use shell script with applescript.
The goal is to change "Icon file" in the application info.plist and copy the icon (file) in the resources of the application. "application".app/Contents/Resources/ " . 
All done in a droplet, on which I drag the desired icon, after opens a window to choose the application whose icon must be changed.
 With plutil I convert the file info.plist to xml1 (which I save under ".app/ Contents/infoo.plist" to avoid any problem and find the original). To change the value "Icon file", I use "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy " with " -c Set: "
to see the change, you have to launch the application (whose icon has been changed), in the dock you have to see the new icon (if the dock option is active)

Below the droplet script

```
    global testdir
on open draggedItems
    repeat with currentItem in draggedItems
        set icon_image_file_string to POSIX path of (draggedItems)
        set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to info for POSIX file icon_image_file_string
        set Nm to do shell script "echo " & Nm & " | sed 's#." & Ex & "##'"

        set testdir to POSIX path of (choose file of type {"APPL"} with prompt "Choisissez  l'Application pour changer son icone  :")
        set {name:Nmm, name extension:Ex} to info for POSIX file testdir

        do shell script "plutil -convert xml1 " & quoted form of (testdir & "Contents/Info.plist ") & " | cat " & quoted form of (testdir & "Contents/Info.plist") & " >" & quoted form of (testdir & "Contents/Infoo.plist")
        try
            do shell script "cp -f " & quoted form of icon_image_file_string & " " & quoted form of (testdir & "Contents/Resources/")
        end try
        try
            set icon_image_file to do shell script "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy   " & quoted form of (testdir & "Contents/Info.plist") & " -c \"Set:CFBundleIconFile " & Nm & "\""
        end try
    end repeat
end open
```